# ¿Como puedo mostrar un elemento de una lista que esta adentro de un objeto angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Tengo una pregunta sobre como poder sacar un elemento de una lista que esta contenida en un objecto

Muestro el objeto:

```
Lista: {…}
ID: 6
NACIONALIDAD: "mexicana                                          "
NOMBRES: "Juan"
PERIODO: "201960"

Mensaje: "encontrado"
Status: true
```

Tengo las siguientes interfaces:

```
export interface ResultadoDatosProspecto {
  Mensaje: string,
  Status: boolean,
  Lista: Array<GetDatosProspecto>

}

export interface GetDatosProspecto {
  ID: number,
  NACIONALIDAD: string,
  NOMBRES: string,
  PERIODO: string
}
```

Y lo trato de obtener de la siguiente manera:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private datosService: DatosService) {
        let Expediente = '12345678';
        this.resultado = false;


        this.datosService.getProspecto(Expediente).subscribe( res => {

          console.log(res)
          this.ResultadosDatosProspecto = res;
          if (this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Status == false){

            this.resultado = false;
          } else if (this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Status == true){
            console.log(this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Status);

            this.resultado = true;
          }
          console.log(this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Mensaje);
          console.log(this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Lista[0].ID);
        });
        }
```

Lo que si nos imprime es el status y el mensaje, lo que necesito saber es de que manera poder imprimir un elemento de la lista definida.

Lo que nos da el console.log(this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Lista[0].ID); es undefined.

Comment: Compruebe por qué `this.ResultadosDatosProspecto.Lista[0]` es `undefined`.

Comment: Parece que el servicio no devuelve una lista si no un objecto, según el primer bloque de código que pusiste `{…}` si fuera un array te saldría algo como esto `[{…}]`. Revisa realmente lo que te esta devolviendo el servicio.